# Change xscreensaver lock option command

Tags: linux, command-line, command-line-arguments, screensaver

How could I change an option (like lock) for the [xscreensaver](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xscreensaver1.html) from the command line? 
Been looking around and couldn't find anything about it. 

`xscreensaver-command -lock` will lock it right away, which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find an actual command to change the `lock` feature, but in the configuration file `.xscreensaver`, located in the home folder, I've found the value of lock: `lock:     False`

So, in order to modify its value, I can change the value in the config file by using the command:

`sed -i 's/\(lock:\t\t\).*/\1False/' /home/username/.xscreensaver`

`False` can be replaced with `True` based on the requirements.